# cursor.commit() not working in Python for data upload into Trino

Tags: python, cursor, commit, execute, trino

I can pull data from Trino into Python and manipulate it but when I go to try to upload the manipulated data into a new table, nothing gets committed. I can DROP/CREATE the same table in DBeaver fine, but if I try to do something as simple as dropping the table via python - it does not work. I don't get an error, but nothing is committed.

Example of code that does work:

```
# Importing required packages
from trino.dbapi import connect
from trino.auth import BasicAuthentication

# Establishing a connection to Trino
trino_conn=connect(
host='hostname.example.com',
port=8443,
user='user',
catalog='system',
schema='runtime',
http_scheme='https',
auth=BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
)
trino_conn._http_session.verify = False
cursor = trino_conn.cursor()

query = """
SELECT  * FROM db.schema.sample_table
"""

cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
columns = [rows[0] for rows in cursor.description]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

After successfully creating the table
**sample_table_II** in DBeaver, the following code does not drop it in Python:

```
# Importing required packages
from trino.dbapi import connect
from trino.auth import BasicAuthentication

# Establishing a connection to Trino
trino_conn=connect(
host='hostname.example.com',
port=8443,
user='user',
catalog='system',
schema='runtime',
http_scheme='https',
auth=BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
)
trino_conn._http_session.verify = False
cursor = trino_conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE db.schema.sample_table_II")
trino_conn.commit()
```

Keep in mind that **cursor.commit()** works fine for me when I am working with Teradata:

```
import teradatasql
teradata_conn = teradatasql.connect(host='hostname.example.com', user='XXXXXXXXXX', password='XXXXXXXXXX')
cursor = teradata_conn.cursor()
```

Comment: The first example has `xxxxxxxx` as the tablename, but the second example has `xxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.  What do the first two dotted parts mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, see my edits. @John Gordon

Comment: Have you tried it without `db.schema.`, i.e. just `DROP TABLE sample_table_II`?

Comment: I Just tried: DROP TABLE schema.sample_table_II, as well as: DROP TABLE sample_table_II. Same issue. :( I can drop tables and commit changes in Teradata if that helps. @JohnGordon

Comment: What happens if you run the second code sample twice in a row?  Does it complain about "no such table" on the second run?

Comment: Does your database user have permission to drop tables?

Comment: @JohnGordon It does not, and I have permission yes. I have dropped/created the same table via DBeaver, changes in Python just won't commit.

Comment: Try executing a SHOW TABLES command before and after the drop.

Comment: Are you able to commit other kinds of changes in Python?  i.e. a simple INSERT?

Comment: Like this? @JohnGordon
```cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")```
```cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO db.schema.sample_table_II VALUES (3463, 1295698, 114, 202, '2023-05-30 14:56:48.283'""")```
```trino_conn.commit()```
```cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")```
Nothing, again :(

Comment: Well, I meant to execute SHOW TABLES and then actually **print the results**, to see if the table is present before and after the drop within the current database session.  Executing the command by itself, without printing the results, is pointless.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I've never used that command before. There are probably 10's of thousands of tables in this database it would be hard to pick it out, but troubleshooting with DBeaver gives me the same insight - the table is present before the DROP in Python, as well as after. @JohnGordon

Comment: Does that table have data in it?  If so, then after the code unsuccessfully drops the table is the data still there?

Comment: And was that INSERT command successfully committed?

Comment: Are you using the exact same credentials to log in with DBeaver?

Comment: @JohnGordon Correct - I created a table with a bunch of data in DBeaver and Python unsuccessfully DROPs the table. No data could be INSERTed via Python either, although I can do it in DBeaver fine. The credentials are the same. I am lost!

Comment: ^ The data still remains after the DROP. @JohnGordon

Comment: & I don't get any Python error messages, it just never actually ends up committing the changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the environment I was working in had too many dependencies with the **trino** package because when I created a new environment via:

```
conda create -n trino_env python=3.7 anaconda
conda activate trino_env
```

and then used:

```
pip install trino
```

Python was able to commit the changes I was trying to make to the database.